# Oven door hinge sticking

Tags: oven, hinges

Given the extended high temperatures inside an oven, I’m wondering what to use as lubricant on the oven door hinges. (One of them is catching and periodically takes a big tug to open.)

Comment: Graphite.  Would check the hinge for any damage.

Comment: It is possible that one of the hinges has actually snapped.  Some doors are designed to be removed by the user for cleaning.  Do you have a manual to see if yours are ?  On mine, you open the door a little bit and lift the door up.

Comment: Maybe one of the springs is jammed up or there is an internal obstruction.